# How do I create a folder for my Android app which will be visible at the same level of DCIM, Downloads, Ringtones, Pictures etc

Tags: android, filesystems, android-file

I want to create a folder for my app (through code off course) which will be visible at the same level where some of the system folders e.g. DCIM, Downloads, Ringtones, Pictures are. I don't have a sdcard mounted.

I have tried the following options but none of them are creating the folder at the desired location and none of them are visible when I connect my phone to my laptop through USB.

**Attempt 1**

```
File appDir = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "ABC");
```

**Attempt 2**

```
File appDir = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "ABC");
```

**Attempt 3**

```
File appDir = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "ABC");
```

**Attempt 4**

```
File appDir = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(android.os.Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "../ABC");
```

Can someone please help?

**EDIT:**
As per the answer of [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) following code created and showed the folder at correct location.

```
File appDir = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "ABC");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(appDir, "test"));
byte buffer[] = new byte[100];
fos.write(buffer, 0, 100);
fos.close();
String paths[] = {new File(appDir, "test").getAbsolutePath()};
String mimeTypes[] = {null};
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, paths, mimeTypes, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
        // Nothing to do
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> none of them are creating the folder at the desired location

"Attempt 3" is.

> none of them are visible when I connect my phone to my laptop through USB

The first two will not be visible, because they are on [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), which is inaccessible for browsing on production hardware.

The latter two will not be visible until you write a file out to the directory, then use `MediaScannerConnection` and its `scanFile()` method to have `MediaStore` add the file to the index. Even after this, you may still need to do a "refresh" operation in your notebook's file manager to see the new file (and the directory holding it).

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware of that `MediaScanner` bit. I have edited my question to include the code snippet.